# How to show the area without chips if there is no value

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-template

[image]My table uses chips to input for the value under "type". but when there is no values in it. there still is a empty chip in it. anyone knows how i can fix this problem?

```
[![html

 <ng-container matColumnDef="type">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header="type">Type</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let truck" class="pr-24">
        <mat-chip-list>
          <span *ngFor="let truck of truck.type.split(',')">
            <mat-chip>{{truck}}</mat-chip>
          </span>
        </mat-chip-list>
      </td>
  </ng-container>][1]][1]
```

---

component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, ElementRef, Input, OnChanges } from '@angular/core';
import { MatPaginator, MatSort, MatTableDataSource, MatDialog, MatChipsModule,  MatChipInputEvent } from '@angular/material';
import { SelectionModel } from '@angular/cdk/collections';
import { Truck } from '../truck';
import { MapsAPILoader } from '@agm/core';
import { TruckDetailComponent } from '../truck-detail/truck-detail.component';
import { PlannerProject } from 'app/services/planner-projects/planner-project';
import { TrucksService } from '../trucks.service';
import { map, debounceTime, distinctUntilChanged, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import * as _ from 'lodash';
import { fromEvent } from 'rxjs';
import { ConfirmComponent } from 'app/shared/components/confirm/confirm.component';
import { FuseConfirmDialogComponent } from '@fuse/components/confirm-dialog/confirm-dialog.component';
import { MyDialogComponent } from 'app/main/delivery-orders/my-dialog/my-dialog.component';
import {COMMA, ENTER} from '@angular/cdk/keycodes';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-trucks',
  templateUrl: './trucks.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./trucks.component.scss']

})
export class TrucksComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {
  @Input() project: PlannerProject;

  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;
  @ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;

  selection: SelectionModel<Truck>;

  _displayColumns: string[] = ['selectCol', 'truckSize', 'truckBuildUp', 'truckName', 'type', 'address', 'shift', 'maxWeight', 'maxVolume', 'actions'];

  _dataSource: MatTableDataSource<Truck>;

  @ViewChild('search') search: ElementRef;
  projectData: string;

  constructor(private mapsLoader: MapsAPILoader,
              private _matDialog: MatDialog,
              private truckService: TrucksService) { }
```

So it should show an empty area in the row without chips if there is no data

Comment: Use *ngIf="truck.type" in <mat-chip-list>

Comment: `split` on an empty string will return an array with 1 item which is empty. Add a check to see if truck.type is empty string then not show

Comment: I highly recommend to not reuse your variables like that.  Use different variable names, not only "truck" for multiple meanings.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

add an *ngIf to your chip, this will make it show only when the condition is satisfied inside the *ngIf.

```
<mat-chip *ngIf="truck">{{truck}}</mat-chip>
```

Comment: But what if truck exists but is an empty string? Does ngIf also check for empty strings?

Comment: Just checked it in pure JavaScript: A simple if(truck) is suffice to check for empty strings. Therefore this answer is simpler and more elegant than mine.

Comment: @RaphaelMayer thanks mate, your answer works too. both of them is great! thanks for you guys help!

Comment: Glad we helped, thanks @RaphaelMayer for mentioning that which can clarify things even further for the OP.

Answer (score 2):

`Array.split()` on an empty string returns an array with 1 empty string. Add a check using `*ngIf="truck.type"` to your chip list to only render when it is not emtpy.

```js
var truck = {type: '' };

var s = truck.type.split(',');

console.log(s); // See Array with one item.
```

Answer (score 2):

I would check if truck.type is empty, because split will return an array of size 1 if it cannot split the string, therefore returning an empty string. This is the reason you get empty chips.

```
<mat-chip-list *ngIf="truck && truck.type && truck.type.length > 0">
  <span *ngFor="let truck of truck.type.split(',')">
    <mat-chip>{{truck}}</mat-chip>
  </span>
</mat-chip-list>
```

Edit: changed *ngIf check for truck and truck.type

Comment: I would also recommend to check for trim(truck.type).length > 0 in case there are whitespaces in your string.